# mssql bulk update procedures and functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

we have some database with a lot of views, functions and procedures.
We will update some of them. Therefore i´ve written this script.
My question is, is that a common way and is that the right way?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
--  update procedures and functions
USE mydb
GO
DECLARE @ticker nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @definition nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @newdefinition nvarchar(max)
DECLARE crsVorgang SCROLL CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ROUTINE_NAME,ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_CATALOG = 'mydb' and ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%something%' 
    ORDER BY ROUTINE_NAME 

        OPEN crsVorgang
        FETCH FIRST FROM crsVorgang INTO @ticker, @definition

        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
        BEGIN

            set @newdefinition = REPLACE(@definition,'sometext', 'newtext')

            --print @newdefinition
            update INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
            set ROUTINE_DEFINITION = @newdefinition
            where ROUTINE_NAME = @ticker

        FETCH NEXT FROM crsVorgang INTO @ticker, @definition
        END
    CLOSE crsVorgang
    DEALLOCATE crsVorgang
GO
```

Comment: as a first response, i tried it on a testsystem and get the following message: Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?  It's really not clear from the above script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, it is not possible with update INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES, cause it is not allowed.

The right way (for me) to a reproduceable bulk update from lots of procedures and functions is now a drop and create, so i have modified my script to the following:

```
USE [mydb]
GO
DECLARE @ticker nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @definition nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @routinetype nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @newdefinition nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @dropdefinition nvarchar(max)
DECLARE crsVorgang SCROLL CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ROUTINE_NAME,ROUTINE_DEFINITION, ROUTINE_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_CATALOG = 'mydb' and ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%something%' 
    ORDER BY ROUTINE_NAME 

        OPEN crsVorgang
        FETCH FIRST FROM crsVorgang INTO @ticker, @definition, @routinetype

        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
        BEGIN

            set @dropdefinition = 'DROP '+ @routinetype +' [dbo].'+@ticker
            set @newdefinition = REPLACE(@definition,'sometext', 'newtext')

            exec (@dropdefinition)
            exec (@newdefinition)

        FETCH NEXT FROM crsVorgang INTO @ticker, @definition, @routinetype
        END
    CLOSE crsVorgang
    DEALLOCATE crsVorgang
GO
```

thanks for your spent time